# Array of objects not getting parsed as javascript array of native objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, parsing

I am receiving following data from server

```
"[{\"role_id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"administrator\",\"created_by_user_id\":\"2\",\"time_created_on\":null,\"is_user_based\":\"0\"},{\"role_id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"manager\",\"created_by_user_id\":null,\"time_created_on\":null,\"is_user_based\":\"0\"}]"
```

which is simply an array of two objects  . Even after setting 'dataType' to json I am not receiving native javascript array inside my success callback function but if I use

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        url:'/public/admin/role/list',
        dataType:'json'

    });


$.ajax({
    success:function(data) {
    alert(data[0].name); // alert box pop up as 'undefined ' 
    var data = $.parseJSON(data); 
    alert(data[0].name) ; //works 
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't escape the `"`. They're required for JSON parsing.

```
[{"role_id":"1","name":"administrator","created_by_user_id":"2","time_created_on":null,"is_user_based":"0"},{"role_id":"2","name":"manager","created_by_user_id":null,"time_created_on":null,"is_user_based":"0"}]
```

Comment: @jason: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @jason - the outer quotes make it a string and strings do need inner quotes "quoted".  Using `parseJSON` on the resulting string unpacks the string into an object.  You just need to return the object itself.  I suspect on the server-side you're double-quoting the quotes `\\"` and starting the string with `"\"[...`.  Drop the opening/closing quotes and don't double quote on the server and you'll be ok.

Comment: @tvanfosson: You should post your answer. I think you're right. OP is encoding it twice server side. I get the same result in the console with `JSON.stringify( JSON.stringify( [{"role_id":"1",...}] ) );`

Answer (score 0):

You have a trailing comma when setting dataType in your ajaxSetup method:

```
dataType:'json',
               ^
```

Also I hope those `\` in the JSON you have shown here are not part of the actual response from the server. The response should look like this:

```
[{"role_id":"1","name":"administrator","created_by_user_id":"2","time_created_on":null,"is_user_based":"0"},{"role_id":"2","name":"manager","created_by_user_id":null,"time_created_on":null,"is_user_based":"0"}]
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out but it was a mistake during copy and paste.

Comment: @jason bournem so the server sends the JSON as shown in my answer? If this is the case it should work without the need to call any $.parseJSON. Also ensure that there are no surrounding `"`.